# php check if session_write_close() has been called(aka, is the session currently writable)

Tags: php, session

I am trying to figure out if there is a recommended way to check if the current session is still writable, but I cant seem to find any changes in the global var or the cookie that would seem to indicate that the session was not writable.

my make do solution was to make a function that contained:

```
@session_start();
```

is this a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your own session_handler (see http://php.net/session_set_save_handler)
for more control.

But the session should remain writeable throughout the lifetime of the script. [session_write_close](http://php.net/session_write_close)() is called automatically at script shutdown.

If session_write_close() is called manually this is probably for a reason. Restarting the session would cause a another (unnecessary) session_write.

Comment: ok will look into the session handler. The reason for the call to session_write_close() is because all of my scripts need to be able to be executed in parallel, because the application is making asynchronous calls. I could just force myself to always call session_write_close(), and then always restart it when I need it...but if I pass this project off to someone else I would rather them not have to worry about it.

Comment: in short I found that session control should stay primarily in the controller, and using the session for an adhoc cache is a bad idea and file caching is easy enough, if you have access to it APC or memcache are probably better solutions for caching...unfortunately I don't have access to either. Thanks for the suggestion about session handlers bob.

Answer (score 0):

I think this excellent tutorial explaining how to [storing session in a database](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database) could help you?

Also I think `session_start()` should be called at top of script and it is always writable?

```
<?php
// page1.php

session_start();
```